# C System Programming clone() flag bit values and Operations

Tags: c, linux

I am very new to system programming in C, I looking at the man page for clone(), it has a bunch of flags. It also gives you an example:

```
pid = clone(childFunc, stackTop, CLONE_NEWUTS | SIGCHLD, argv[1]);
```

First question, I look through the man page for clone() and it doesn't to give you any numeric values for the flags but it does mention that "flags may also be bitwise-or'ed with zero or more of the following constants". Where can I find the numeric values for these flags.

Secondly, what is the logic behind the statement

```
CLONE_NEWUTS | SIGCHLD
```

What is actually happening here? I know bitwise OR, but what does it do with these flags and what is the result of ORing the two flags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First question:**

See your system's "sched.h" for CLONE_NEWUTS (likely 0x04000000), and "signal.h" for SIGCHLD (likely 20). If you look at "sched.h" you may find that the signal mask (CSIGNAL) is set to 0x000000FF, which feeds into question 2...

**Second question:**

From the Linux man pages (man7.org):

> If CLONE_NEWUTS is set, then create the process in a new UTS
>   namespace, whose identifiers are initialized by duplicating
>   the identifiers from the UTS namespace of the calling process.
>   If this flag is not set, then (as with fork(2)) the process is
>   created in the same UTS namespace as the calling process.
>   This flag is intended for the implementation of containers.

And

> The low byte of flags contains the number of the termination signal sent to          the parent when the child dies. If this signal is specified as anything other than SIGCHLD, then the parent process must specify the __WALL or __WCLONE options when waiting for the child with wait(2). If no signal is specified, then the parent process is not signaled when the child terminates.

I would suggest that this does just that - creates the cloned process in a new UTS namespace, and signals the parent process with SIGCHLD once terminated.